# Как считать значения Radiobutton с помощью Bottle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, вопрос довольно простой - не получается получить значения (value) radiobutton. Код примера ниже.
**app.py:** (закомеченный код тоже не работает)

```
from bottle import route, run, debug, template, request, post, get

@get('/answer')
def answer():
    #otvet = "ничего"
    #if 'nedzen' == request.forms.get('dzen'):
    #   otvet = "Не Дзен"
    #if 'dzen' == request.forms.get('dzen'):
    #   otvet = "Дзен"
    #if 'pdzen' == request.forms.get('dzen'):
    #   otvet = "Полный Дзен"
    ops = request.forms.get('dzen')
    #ops = request.form['dzen']
    if ops == 'nedzen':
        otvet = "Не Дзен"
    elif ops == 'dzen':
        otvet = "Дзен"
    elif ops == 'pdzen':
        otvet = "Полный Дзен"
    else:
        otvet = "Ничего"
    return "<p>Ты выбрал пункт " + otvet

@route('/')
def index():
    return template('pro.tpl', request=request)
```

**pto.tpl:**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Probyem</title>

<h1>Выбираем категорию</h1>
<form action="/answer" method="get">
<p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="nedzen">Не дзен</p>
<p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen">Дзен</p>
<p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="pdzen" checked>Полный дзен</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
</form>
```

На выходе получается, что "Ты выбрал ничего". Сам объект ops типа NoneType. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы метод get у формы используете, а не post. Подозреваю значения в урле приходят: `request.query.dzen`

Comment: @jfs благодарю, заработало

Comment: если нашли решение, то в виде ответа добавьте—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По подсказкам в комментариях (спасибо [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs)) была найдена ошибка.

Для получения параметров через **GET** используется **BaseRequest.query**, либо можно получить через **BaseRequest.params** или **BaseRequest.GET**.

Через **BaseRequest.forms** данные можно получить только через **POST**. 
Хорошая поясняющая табличка есть на сайте фреймворка - http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#html-form-handling

Чтобы пример выше заработал, нужно всего лишь изменить строчку

```
ops = request.forms.get('dzen')
```

на

```
ops = request.query.dzen
```

Примеры выполнения:

[image: Правильное выполнение]

[image: Случай, когда в параметрах другое значение]